# Extracting XML data using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, ajax

```
   <!--  http://www.abc.com  -->
    <rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
    <title>SENSEX view</title>
    <link>http://www.abc.com</link>
    <copyright>Copyright 2009, abc</copyright>
    <item>
    <title>
    <![CDATA[ SENSEX : 20263.71 * -382.93 (-1.85 %) ]]>
    </title>
    <link/>
    <pubDate>9/20/2013 4:00:00 PM</pubDate>
    <author>abc</author>
    <guid/>
    </item>
    </channel>
    </rss>
```

I want to extract "`<![CDATA[ SENSEX : 20263.71 * -382.93 (-1.85 %) ]]>`" from above XML data in a variable. I am not familiar handling  XML using javascript. So i need some help or suggest me some tutorials ??

Here's what i have got :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://rss.xml",
    dataType: "xml",.find("title")
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find("title").each(function(){

            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            $(this).find('title').each(function()
            {
                alert(title );

            });
        });
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is trying to find "site" which is not an element within your xml, nor is there any attributes named "id", if you want the "title" data use `.find("title")`

Comment: You seem to need the content of the `title` element present within `each` `item` element. There are clues there :)

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using jquery ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `success` callback code to:

```
success: function(xml) {
         $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                 $(this).find('title').each(function(){
         var title = $(this).text();
         alert(title);
       });
       });
    }
```

And without jQuery:

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("yourFile.xml");
var title = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
alert(title);

function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using jquery ??

Comment: '<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function callme()
{
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("http://sensexrss.xml");
var title = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
document.getElementById('aa').innerHTML =title;
}

function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="callme()">
<div id="aa">
</div>
</body>
</html>'